# Rails / Active Support "to_sentence" deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

I was just getting rolling with the "to_sentence" method when I discovered that it was [deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Conversions/to_sentence) in rails > 2.3.8. Does anyone know why and whether it's been replaced? I find it awfully handy and would hate to lose that bit of functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They just [moved it](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence), that's all. It can be misleading when they label things as "deprecated" when they're talking about a particular implementation, not a feature.

It's now defined as an extension of Array.